# Filter Blackberry simulator console output messages

Tags: console, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using the Blackberry Simulator plugin with Eclipse. I have a few System.out.println statements in order to view the values at runtime but the output has lots of RIM messages.

The question is, is there a way to filter out these messages from the ones I want to see from the println statements ?

Thanks,
Siri

Comment: +1. can't find an answer on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Not actually filtering, but may help: [Grep Console Eclipse Plug-In: Color your console](http://mackaz.de/8)

Comment: Note that when installing Grep Console, you need to uncheck 'Group items by category' in the Install dialog to see the available items.